# My program seems to be skipping my "If" statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a C# application that submits information to an Access database. I fill in three required boxes , and click "Submit". The script should respond in the following manner when the use clicks the button:

Step 1. Look into database Table A, to see if the value in textBox1 exists in the database.

Step 2. If the value exists, add the values of textBox1, textBox2, and textBox3 into database Table B columns, respectively.

Step 3. If any one of the three text boxes are left blank, display a message.

Step 4. If the value in textBox1 is not in the database table, display a message. (eventually, I plan the replace the message with a default population of the database fields)

***THE PROBLEM:*** When I run the program, in any of the above cases, the result is Step number 4 above. It seems to skip the first "if" statement, and jumping right to the "else" outcome.

Any help resolving this, would be greatly appreciated! The "Private Void "code is below.
Thanks in advance.

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from script_Orders where cust_Name = @UserID", vcon);
     OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter();
     param.ParameterName = "@UserID";
     param.Value = textBox1.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
     OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     {    
         if (reader.HasRows)
         {
             if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "")
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("You must fill in all fields.");
                 return;
             }
             else
             {
                 OleDbCommand dbCommand;
                 OleDbDataReader dbReader;
                 new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=C:\Search\Database.accdb");
                 dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) as Record_Count from script_received", vcon);
                 dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                  if (dbReader.Read() == true)
                      rowCount = dbReader["Record_Count"].ToString();
                  else
                      return;

                  var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                  {
                      using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO script_Received (script, qty, emp_id, received_Date) VALUES (@script,@qty,@emp_Id,@rec_date)"))
                      {
                          command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                          command.Parameters.Add("@script", OleDbType.Integer).Value = textBox1.Text;
                          command.Parameters.Add("@qty", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
                          command.Parameters.Add("@emp_id", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
                          command.Parameters.Add("@rec_date", OleDbType.Date).Value = date;
                          command.Connection = vcon;
                          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                      }
                      this.textBox1.Clear();
                      this.textBox2.Clear();
                      this.textBox1.Focus();
                  }
             }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The value of textBox1  is not in the orders table");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you debug this?  Is there an error?  What are the states of the objects when the conditionals are evaluated?  Maybe a value is different than you expect?

Comment: Now that's a pretty severe case of indentation abuse.

Comment: I suspect if you actually debug this thing, you'll find that `reader` is `null`... why do you think that is? *Hint hint:* look closely at your connection boilerplate code, you're missing *something*...

Comment: A side note: make sure to dispose your reader and connection.

Comment: @ErOx if Reader is null, it'll crash on .HasRows(). He won't get to his 4th condition. And tell him what he's missing. That's why he's here.

Comment: @Cicada it's like an even-worse version of [GNU-style indentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allman_style#GNU_style)

Comment: What I'm saying is that the connection is never actually opened anywhere to begin with, which will cause this code to always jump to the message box block (whether that's condition 4, i don't know, i didn't bother to sort through the if/else/if/else madness)

Comment: You need to reevaluate the order of your conditions in the code and your stated steps. They don't match. Also, you probably want to check that textBox1.Text actually has a value before trying to use it in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it jumps to the `else` of `if(reader.HasRows)` without throwing any exceptions, then `reader` must not be `null`, and it's `HasRows` property must be `false`.  That means your query executed successfully but returned no rows.

You might try running the `select` statement by hand, which might help you understand what's wrong. Most likely, you're typing something in the textbox that doesn't match any of the `cust_name` values.